# Como mantener los links de img src en componentes de una libreria en angular empaquetada con ng-packagr?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

Tengo una librería para practicar y quise publicarla. En la librería tengo componentes que usan etiquetas img src con la ruta relativa : `'../../assets/...'` y cuando empaqueto el proyecto con ng-pacakgr coloco assets dentro de `src/libs`.

Pero cuando añado los componentes en otro proyecto las imágenes no cargan... busca las imágenes en la dirección local del proyecto que importa mi librería no coge el assets de la libreria del node_modules. La verdad nunca he hecho nada de esto y no encuentro nada por ningún lado.

Comment: En el src de tus *img* debería ir solo desde **assets**, ejemplo: `<img src='assets/...'`. ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM he probado poniendo eso tal cual y nada he probado con assets con /assets con src/ nada siempre igual... pero gracias!

Comment: La librería presenta un archivo de configuración `angular.json`? Si es así, de qué manera está asignado el campo `assets`.

Hay una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741052/include-assets-when-building-angular-library) (en inglés) que te podría servir de referencia.